# Do not have permission to call setValues

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Im writing a function in google sheets app script, the purpose of which is to copy the contents and formatting of a cell on another sheet called Key which serves as a legend for the other sheets in the document.

```
/**
 * @param {string} cell The cell reference
 * @customfunction
 */
function KEY_COPY(cell) {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Key");
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(cell);
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getActiveRange(); // Get the range of the active cell
  
  var ftc = sourceRange.getFontColorObject().asRgbColor();
  var bgc = sourceRange.getBackground();
  //var bdc = sourceRange.getBorder(null, null, null, null, null, null).getColor();
  
  targetRange.setValues(sourceRange.getValues());
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {formatOnly:true});
}
```

i removed the border functionality to try to get it working, and its giving me a permission error. I fiddled with permissions for a while and my other functions work fine. Based on reading other questions of this sort, I think it may be trying to set values to the wrong cell, as that can return this sort of error. I am aware a custom function can only modify the cell its located in, and thats exactly what I want to do. Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

With Custom Functions you can only use readonly methods.  So you cannot change the contents of another cell or sheet

- [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced)

You can do this with a standard function that is run from a menu.  You can use active range to page the cell location or perhaps a UI.prompt.

Comment: My intention was to write a function which would do this that I could enter into cells, which would bind them to a parent cell in the Key sheet and allow them to inherit its formatting and contents. It seems that the custom menu allows me to copy the format and contents when I click to run it in the custom menu, but would it permanently define that cell as being associated with the parent cell, allowing its content and format to update automatically when the parent cell updates? This is my goal

Comment: Custom Functions are functions that you enter into cells like formulas.  I don't understand what the parent cell of a cell is  or perhaps more precisely the parent range of a range.